# Why does scipy.stats.entropy(a, b) return inf while scipy.stats.entropy(b, a) doesn't?

Tags: python, scipy

```
In [15]: a = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0])

In [16]: b = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [17]: entropy(a, b)
Out[17]: inf

In [18]: entropy(b, a)
Out[18]: 0.6931471805599453
```

From their [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html), I expected both to return `inf` since the equation given is `S = sum(pk * log(pk / qk), axis=0)`. What is the reason for the non-infinite output in line 18?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `entropy(b, a)` function calculates the first pair:

```
>>> 1 * np.log(1/0.5)
>>> 0.6931471805599453
```

For `entropy(a, b)`, there is one case of divide-by-zero, `0.5/0`, which leads to an infinite solution.

For the rest, `entropy()` assumes `0 * np.log(0/0) = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the definition of the Kullback-Leibler divergence, it seems like it is due to how it is defined.

This is from Wikipedia:

> Whenever  P(x) is zero the contribution of the corresponding term is interpreted as zero because
>   [the limit goes to zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTYBb.jpg) (click link for the equation).

Answer (score 0):

When both p and q are provided the entropy function computes the KL-divergence. The KL-divergence is asymmetric meaning that `KL(p,q)!=KL(q,p)` unless `p==q`. Therefore you will get different answers.

Further on, as the other answers explains the fact that you have zeros in your distribution means that we will divide by zero according to the definition of the KL-divergence.

```
    KL(p,q) = sum(p * log(p/q))
```